# Git Operations Fails on Remote Repositories (credential-manager errors)

Tags: git, git-for-windows

Suddenly, git fetch, push, pull, clone etc. commands are stopped working. Firstly, It came out inside Visual Studio's Team Explorer, then I tried cmd, PowerShell and Git Bash. Only Git Bash is working. I tried re-installing both Visual Studio, Git, Git Credential Manager. I also deleted all the cached credentials from Windows' User accounts and various places.I also tried changing credential-helpers too.
Powershell output is:

```
error: waitpid for git credential-manager get failed: No child processes
error: waitpid for git credential-manager store failed: No child processes
error: waitpid for git credential-manager store failed: No child processes
```

Visual Studio's output is:

```
Fetching from origin
Error encountered while fetching: Git failed with a fatal error.
'credential-manager' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-credential-manager is broken?
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
'credential-store' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-credential-store is broken?
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!
'credential-manager' appears to be a git command, but we were not
able to execute it. Maybe git-credential-manager is broken?
cannot spawn /c/program files (x86)/microsoft visual studio/2017/enterprise/common7/ide/commonextensions/microsoft/teamfoundation/team explorer/Git/mingw32/libexec/git-core/git-askpass.exe: No such file or directory could not read Password for 'https://xx@xxx.com': terminal prompts disabled
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is there any update on this issue?

Comment: Unfortunately, I forgot how it is solved, I don't even remember I asked this. Maybe more than one git version installed at the same time?